# Proceed to execute next cURL statement only if Progress = 100% or status = complete else wait for it to get to 100%

Tags: shell-script, curl

I am trying to automate a chunk of cURL code. I am stuck at this step where I need to ensure percentComplete = 100% or status = complete before I can move forward. Here is the i/p -

```
curl -XGET -H 'X-API-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://xx1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys/XX_XXXXXXXXXXX/export-responses/XX_XXXXXXXXX
```

Here's the output -

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   188  100   188    0     0    541      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   540{"result":{"fileId":"xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx","percentComplete":100.0,"status":"complete"},"meta":{"requestId":"xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx","httpStatus":"200 - OK"}}
```

I have tried using regex such that it extracts the status and compares it with "complete" as follows -

```
while [$(curl -XGET -H 'X-API-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://xx1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys/XX_XXXXXXXXXXX/export-responses/XX_XXXXXXXXX | sed -E -n 's/.*status":"([a-z]+).+/\1/p')!= "complete"]; 
do sleep 5s;
done
```

Comment: The `curl` process will not exit until it's done, you don't need to parse its output.

Comment: @Wieland+ you don't need to parse for curl's 'progress' (which is on stderr not stdout anway) because it won't exit until receiving (and outputting) the whole response, but the "server":"complete" here is _data from the server_ which OP does need to look for/at. OP: you need a space after `[` and before `]` for them to be recognized correctly as a shell test, and between `$(...) !=`.You could also turn off the progress display with `-q` to reduce clutter.

Comment: thank you @Wieland

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used suggestions from the comments and I created the following which worked for me-
Note - $VAR is the output of a previous command that I am using here.

```
VAR2="$(curl -f -XGET -H 'X-API-TOKEN: XXXXXXXXX' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://xxx.qualtrics.com/xx_xxxxxxx/export-responses/"$VAR" | sed -E -n 's/.*status":"([a-z]+).+/\1/p')"
echo $VAR2
#sleep 10s
a=1
while [ $a = 1 ]
do
    if [ $VAR2 != 'complete' ]
    then
        VAR2="$(curl -f -XGET -H 'X-API-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://xx.qualtrics.com/xxxxxxxxx/export-responses/"$VAR" | sed -E -n 's/.*status":"([a-z]+).+/\1/p')"
        sleep 3s
    else
        a=`expr $a + 2`
    fi
done
```